# How to filter all data with pagination - angular material

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm creating a test project, where I have a list of users that comes with pagination.
I managed to create a filter that checks 4 fields: lastname, firstname, email and username, but it only works on the first page. I wanted the filter to work on the entire list. I tried to replicate the logic that is in the Angular Material documentation but I had no result. can you help me?

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field class="matfield" appearance="outline">
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastname" (input)="Search()" placeholder="Pesquisar">
  <mat-icon matSuffix color="primary">
    search
    </mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-table [dataSource]="usuarios">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.firstName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sobrenome</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.lastName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.username }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E-mail</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.email }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="action-column">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="accent"
          title="Adicionar um Usuário"
          (click)="onAdd()"
          class="action-column-header"
        >
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-header-cell>

      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-column">


        <button button mat-icon-button class="botao-enviar" title="Gerar Nova Senha"
          (click)="onSend(element)">
          <mat-icon>outgoing_mail</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button mat-icon-button class="botao-editar" title="Editar Usuário"
          (click)="onEdit(element)">

          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>


      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

Component.ts:

```js
export class GerenciamentoUsuariosListaComponent {
  @Input() usuarios: any[] = [];
  lastname :string = '';
  usuariosFilter : any;
  @Output() add = new EventEmitter(false);
  @Output() edit = new EventEmitter(false);
  @Output() send = new EventEmitter(false);
  @Output() remove = new EventEmitter(false);

  readonly displayedColumns = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username','email','actions'];
  
  constructor(private service: GerenciamentoUsuariosService) {


  }

  onAdd() {
    this.add.emit(true);
  }
  onSend(usuario: Usuario) {
    this.send.emit(usuario)
    console.log(usuario);
  }
  onEdit(usuario: Usuario) {
    this.edit.emit(usuario)
    console.log(usuario);
  }

  refreshFilterListUser() {
    this.usuariosFilter = this.service.listUserFilter(this.lastname).subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.usuarios = resp.content
       console.log(this.usuarios)

      });

  }

  Search(){
    if(this.lastname != "" ){
        this.usuarios = this.usuarios.filter(res =>{
           const keyword = this.lastname.toLocaleLowerCase();
           return res.firstName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) ||
           res.lastName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) ||
           res.username.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) ||
           res.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword);


      })
    }else if(this.lastname == "" ){
      this.refreshFilterListUser();
    }

  }




}
```

Interface:

```js
export interface Usuario {
  id:string;
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  username: string
  email: string
  role: Role
  branch: Branch
  
}

export interface Role {
  id: number
  //authority:string
}

export interface Branch {
  id: number
  //name:string
}


export interface Page {
  content: Usuario[],
  pageable: {
      sort: {
          empty: boolean,
          sorted: boolean,
          unsorted: boolean
      },
      offset: number,
      pageSize: number,
      pageNumber: number,
      unpaged: boolean,
      paged: boolean
  },
  last: boolean,
  totalPages: number,
  totalElements: number,
  size: number,
  number: number,
  sort: {
      empty: boolean,
      sorted: boolean,
      unsorted: boolean
  },
  numberOfElements: number,
  first: boolean,
  empty: boolean
}
```

Service:

```js
.....
  listPageUsers( page:any, size:number): Observable<Page>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Page>(`${this.apiUser}?size=${size}&page=${page}&sort=firstName,asc`).pipe()
  }


  listUserFilter(filter:string){
    return this.httpClient.get<ContentUser>(`${this.apiUser}?search=${filter}`)
      .pipe(
        first(),

      );
  }
```